# Jquery Mobile jump to start page by changing screen orientation

Tags: jquery-mobile, screen-orientation, multipage

I have built a jQuery Mobile application, but I have one issue I don't understand.
I am using the multi-page functionality, but when you are in a page and you change the screen orientation, it jumps back to the start page. I do not understand how to stay on the current page when changing orientation.

I have tried this:

```
$(window).bind("orientationchange", function (e, ui) 
{ 
    var sPage ="#"+$.mobile.activePage.attr("id"); 
    $.mobile.changePage(sPage); 
    alert(sPage);
});
```

The alert() showed the correct page where I want to stay.

Below is an example how is made the multipage. If i select the option 'Instellingen',
This pages showed. But when i change the smartphone orientation, it jumps back to the menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title>Mobile</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="../css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/DataBase.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Webservice.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Misc.js"></script>
</head> 

<body>
<div id="Menu" data-role="page" data-title="Hoofdmenu">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
  </div>
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Hoofd Menu</li>
                <li><a href="#Instellingen"><h3>Instellingen</h3>
<p>Algemene programma instellingen</p></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="Instellingen" data-role="page" data-title="Instellingen">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Programma instellingen</h1>
     <a data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" href="#Menu" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="b">
        Back</a></div>
   <div data-role="content"  data-theme="b">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
      <li><div><h1>WCF adres<input id="Adress" type="url"/></h1> </div> 
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a id="Test" data-role="button">Test</a>
        <a id="Opslaan" data-role="button">Opslaan</a>
                </div></li>
  </ul>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Test").click(function () {
        if ($("#Adress").val().length > 0)
            CheckWebService($("#Adress").val(), function (Check) { alert(Check); })
        else
            alert("Geen adres of error")
    });
    $("#Opslaan").click(function () { saveURL($("#Adress").val()); });
    $("#Dummy").click(function () { alert("dummy"); });
    $("#ResetDatabase").click(function () { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "Sync");  ResetDatabase(); });

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jumping to the original page is a symptom of code error, and you will not be able to prevent it with code mentioned in your question. Can you show us more of your js code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue for months, until today I added the screenSize parameter to the android manifest, as follows:

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

Hope that helps!